# acr122U NFC Tag reading

Tags: c#, android, .net, nfc, smartcard

UPDATE:

let me sum up what i have done so far.
I updated my smartphone to 4.0.4 because of android beam.
The following site allows one to send and receive NDEF Messages:
http://www.grundid.de/nfc/ndef-applet.html

that worked perfectly for me.

After that i was able to write an little app which sends NDEF Tags over an P2P connection.

There is only one topic left: Create a desktop based application to receive the tags.
I implemented the following example from github.com :

https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nfctools/examples/llcp/LlcpService.java

that worked also well. But i just dont know what happens behind the example. The example class uses a package (jar) consisting of *.class files. Its the same as using the applett. My aim is to create code by my self. A complete project.

So is there a way, to receive ndef tags (over p2p) in .net? or java? this is what iam looking for.

Next Steps:

i will try to use the Winscard.dll:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Smart-Cards-in-.NET/

but it seems to be only for SDCards and have nothing to do with NFC.

Have you any suggestions or tips to achieve my gaols? that would be wonderful.

Thank you.

Berry

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this project: http://www.grundid.de/nfc/?

Comment: Yes i did, but i dont need an excisting tool. I need to write one on my own. Is there any possibility to connect to the ACR122?

Comment: That's an Apache licensed project, can't you just *read* the code?

Comment: Is that possible? can you give me a tip how to achieve that?

Comment: that works for android 4.0.4 with android beam, is there a similar way for 2.3.3?

Comment: Why do you assume that it only works for Android 4.0.4? It implements NPP over LLCP, which is supported since 2.3.3.

Comment: Wasnt working for me with 2.3.3. After sending an email to the developer of nfctools he told me that i should update my phone to 4.0.4 because he uses android beam. after updating it worked perfectly. I wrote an App which is able to send ndef tags over p2p to my ACR122. Now i just need to write an tool (.net would be perfect) which is able to reveive the NFC tag! i just dont know how to do that. I implemented the code you mansioned above and the LLCPServiceExample worked for me, but there are only .class files. i cant see the code in that classes. I would like to write it by my self.

Comment: Read a tag using nfctools using ACR 122U with the example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nfc-developers/vDfVCM3CT1g). It is not magic, now is it? ;-)